# Dynamically add or modify RegistrationInformation in Sony Smart watch 2

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I was looking at the source example provided by Sony but didn't find a way to change or modify the layout for Notification API dynamically once it has been registered.

Or in other words , is it possible to dynamically register a `RegistrationInformation` subclass rather than during the service creation time registration.

I'm also aware of a method in `RegistrationInformation` class named `isSourcesToBeUpdatedAtServiceCreation`. But according to documentation it can only update configuration source during service creation only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to dynamically register a Notification extension.  Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve here?